# Does the rsync --archive option override the --exclude option?

Tags: rsync, archive

I am running an `rsync -avz` command which excludes a large 32GB file by using `--exclude=/file/path` and no matter what I do `rsync` transfers the file.

I understand that logically the `--archive` option means mirror everything, but the examination of the `-rlptgoD` options the `--archive` option is equivalent to doesn't seem to explicitly override the `--exclude` option

```
--archive, -a            archive mode is -rlptgoD (no -A,-X,-U,-N,-H)


--recursive, -r          recurse into directories    
--links, -l              copy symlinks as symlinks
--times, -t              preserve modification times
--perms, -p              preserve permissions
--group, -g              preserve group
--owner, -o              preserve owner (super-user only)
-D                       same as --devices --specials
--devices                preserve device files (super-user only)
--specials               preserve special files
```

Comment: If it did, it'd be largely useless (I'm talking about both options here). Is there anything in the path that might cause it to be interpreted as pattern that doesn't match the actual path?

Comment: @muru The point is the `-rlptgoD` it presumably expands to does not seem to exclude the use of the `--exclude` option. I guess I will have to try that option literally with the `--exclude` option to see  if it will work.
The path is an explicit file name rooted from the `/home/user` directory.

Comment: _my point_ is that even explicit filenames can have characters that may be interpreted as something more.

Comment: No, `-a/--archive` does not override `--exclude=path`.  In my rsync commands, when my `--exclude` doesn't seem to work, it's always because rsync views the path to the file as different from the path in my `--exclude` option.  Adding `--list-only` after the other options often shows this difference.

Comment: @SottoVoce This is what I just discovered. I was running it from the home directory using the `.` as the source directory, so neither `~/path/file` nor `/home/user/path/file` would work. I had to use `--exclude=path/file` to get it work.

Please convert your comment to an answer for me to accept it. I will check the documentation to see if this aspect is made explicit.

Comment: The file/path names for the `--include` and `--exclude` options are not necessarily relative to the source. They can start with `/` to anchor them to the source, or omit it to match at any point. Your example of `path/file` for a source directory of `/src` could match `/src/this/is/my/path/file` or `/src/path/file` or any other combination _as long as it contains_ `path/file`

Comment: @ChrisDavies Do you mean that a path option starting as `/src` is rooted to the rsync command's source directory, rather than the root of the file system, ie setting the source to `/home/user` using `/src` in the exclude path means it is the `/home/user/src` path that would be excluded rather than the file systems `/src/` directory?

Comment: @vfclists yes exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-a/--archive` option doesn't override `--exclude`.  In my own rsync commands I've found that when my `--exclude` doesn't seem to work it's always because rsync sees the path to the file(s) as different from the path I put in my `--exclude` argument.

I've found that adding the `--list-only` after my other options will show rsync's path to the file and usually makes the discrepancy visible.